# When base is added to water it produce OH- ions but why does it not react with H2O as when acid is added to water H+ ions forms H3O+ ions?

Tags: acid-base

Why bases produce OH- ions and why this ions Doesn't react with H2O ? Is these ions are stable ? In the case when acid is added it releases H+ ions which then reacts with water to form hydronium ion but why not hydroxide ion ?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE site! When you ask, it is expected you have thoroughly searched and thought about the topic, providing explicit compact summary of partial answers/ideas/thoughts you have got until then. It is quite common requirement across all StackExchange sites. It is evidence of effort and gives the hint what you are already aware of. [How do I ask a good question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you realize H+ - if taken literally - is just a proton/deuteron then you can notice the huge difference between a proton and OH-. Both H3O+ and OH- are further hydrated by H2O molecules via hydrogen bonds.

Comment: What happens to the concentration of OH- when an OH- reacts with a water molecule?